# searching in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a trips table which stores trip details. One of the field stores date and the type is DATETIME . I am creating a search query by date.

```
$q can be
$q = 2012   when searching for years
$q = 1-12   when searching for months
$q = 1-31   when searching for days
```

But when searching, say for **02** month in the tabe and there are many rows some of them being  `2002-02-13 04:44:48, 2013-02-13 04:44:48, 2013-02-13 02:44:48` etc, all of them will be displayed because all of them contain **02** in them. But my intention is to get the row with **02** in the month . How can I do it and what will be the appropriate way.

```
    function search($q){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('trips');
        $this->db->like('date',$q);

        // Execute the query.
        $query = $this->db->get();

        // Return the results.
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

I could accomplish it by storing day, month, year in different fields, But is there anyway to do it in the way I have stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using native sql query you can do

```
$month = 02;
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(date) FROM notification where MONTH(date) = ?;";
$query = $this->db->query($sql,array($month));
```

***MySQL has functions like , month,day,and year to use with datetime fields.***

Answer (score 1):

Try this one instead of your `like` clause:

```
$this->db->where(array('MONTH(`date`)'=>$q));
```